# AWS elasticbeanstalk socket.io error 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a client which opens websocket connection with another server.
When using socket.io I success, but on production I get this error:

Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

I read that I need to create ebextensions config file like this:

```
location / {
                proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8081;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }
```

I tried to proxy also port 8080, and also change to 'localhost', But I still get the error.
BTW I use SSL in my domain.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to telnet to your application port , If that work nginx should do the proxying

Comment: @JamsheerKandoth how is it related to the websocket?